# How do I prevent iTunes from deleting movies, music?

Tags: macos, itunes

I have certain movies downloaded on my Mac for my kids so I always have stuff to watch.  I noticed after a long time (1/2 year or longer) the downloads disappear and I have to re-download them.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you have "Automatically delete watched films and TV programmes" checked in iTunes-Preferences-Advanced?

Comment: No.  I verified it's off.